# Double quotes are not getting added on FilterPattern - AWS Subscription filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to use the following filter pattern - `"error-res-received "`. So on the configuration `yaml` file, I have have given `FilterPattern: "\"error-res-received \""`. But after deploying the lambda with subscription filter, When I check it on cloud watch > log group > subscription filters, the filter pattern is as `error-res-received`(double quotes are missing). So now, it's only picking up the logs which has word only `error` in it and excluding the words `res` and `received`. How can solve this issue? I need the logs which match this sentence "error-res-received".

Comment: Are you sure `FilterPattern: "\"error-res-received \""` did not work? I just tried it and it worked for me? Do you want the result to match the exact phrase of `error-res-received` or do you want the result to match the phrase with quotes?

Comment: I want exact `error-res-received` phrase to match. I was using this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#:~:text=Example%3A-,Match%20exact%20phrases,-The%20following%20code

Answer (score 0):

**To Match exact phrases**

The following code snippet shows an example of a filter pattern that returns log events where messages contain the exact phrase ***INTERNAL SERVER ERROR***.

```
"INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
```

The filter pattern returns the following log event message:

```
[ERROR 500] INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

**To Match everything**

You can match everything in your log events with double quotation marks. The following code snippet shows an example of a filter pattern that returns all log events.

```
" "
```

In your case, `"error-res-received "`, there is extra space at end which might make it to match everything.

Comment: `"error-res-received "`  - I have tested this pattern on subscription filter and it worked fine. I'm declaring filter pattern on yaml file. And it's taking without quotes

Comment: Can you once try with this- FilterPattern: '"error-res-received "'

Comment: There is also another way to escape the quotes in YAML: 
`FilterPattern: >-
      "error-res-received "`

Comment: Nope, it's still creating filter pattern as `error-res-received`